# Permanent Blank Screen after lid close? -Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, hdmi, blank-screen, lid

Can you guys be of assistance? Ubuntu Newbie here.

Hp M6 Envy laptop

I closed my lid to move with my laptop and by the time (10 mins) i opened it the screen was totally blank not black , blank. I restarted many times with no results. Got home and connected the laptop to my tv via hdmi and it works fine but rimary screen remains blank. What could be the problem here? Over the past months i know ubuntu has been known to crash my laptop after suspending.

Comment: Look for one of the Fn - F key combinations to switch video outputs.

Comment: Related / possible-duplicates: http://askubuntu.com/questions/114792/ubuntu-black-screen-after-suspend and http://askubuntu.com/questions/307727/resuming-problem-after-suspending (see also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen)